# UIScrollView - scroll indicator with white points (like on home-screen)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, indicator

I want to change UIScrollview scroll indicator's style.
I have turned paging on and I want to see white points (like on iPhone home-screen) instead of bar. 
It is possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you need to add `UIPageControl` to show scroll indicatior like home. Also don't forgot to change current page of UIPageControl.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Just add one to your view (not in the scroll view though!) and wire it up appropriately. See this question for more as well - [how do i use a UIPageControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487572/how-do-i-use-a-uipagecontrol)