# how to add views to page control

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, uipagecontrol

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.view = scrollView;

pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(50, 350, 50, 50);
pageControl.numberOfPages = 3;
pageControl.currentPage = 0;
[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
```

I am new to iPhone software development. Please give me some code I could use here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i use a UIPageControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487572/how-do-i-use-a-uipagecontrol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)setupPage
    {   
        UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        blueView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 480);
        blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [scrollView addSubview:blueView];   
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 2;
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640, 0)];
    }
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
    {    
        if(pageControlIsChangingPage){
            return;
        }
        CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        pageControl.currentPage = page;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create array of `UIViewControllers` like bellow....

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
```

and then just add the viewControllers or views with for loops like bellow...

```
 NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        [controllers addObject:yourViewControlls];// use different viewControls
    }
    self.viewControllers = controllers;
```

so here 5 viewConreoller are added in array and use it in PageViewController

for more info see this tutorial and example..

[pagecontrol-example-in-iphone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/)

Comment: @Balveer use this link also i hope its helpful to you.. http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html :)

Comment: thanks @paras joshi..and my page control is not seen on every page.and i checked many sample codes bt i have not understood..and i want to do programtically

Comment: UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    blueView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 500, 1024);
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:164.0/256 green:176.0/256 blue:224.0/256 alpha:1];
    [scrollView addSubview:blueView];
    
    UIView *orangeView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    orangeView.frame = CGRectMake(700, 0, 500, 1024);
    orangeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/256 green:196.0/256 blue:131.1/256 alpha:1];
    [scrollView addSubview:orangeView];

Comment: hey @Balveer just read the tutorial which i post link in answer and also its very simple just you add the your view array in pagecontrols just refer in the tutorial u found the code about it and when i'll free i also post the code dude..

Comment: sir i will be thankful if u send me a progrmatically code of uipagecontrol using scrollview and uiview on my email balveer.isit@gmail.com